# How to sort an Array by positive or negative integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Specifically I'm looking to sort an array

```
    array = [1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5];
```

into

```
    array = [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5];
```

Comment: For numbers you generally want to do `array.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; })`.

Answer (score 2):

Try [**Array.prototype.sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

N.B. This method work only if the values are of type Number. If they are strings, the comparison function will break. It will also fail if the array contains `NaN` or `Infinity`.

N.N.B This method mutates the array, i.e. it modifies the array you reference it on, which may or may not be important to you.